# Oracle SQL view

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created this views but I can't get it to work in my database. Does this look alright?
I have to provide this views see below.
All flight reservations made by John Smith including, for those flights that have flown, the duration of the flight.

```
CREATE VIEW ViewA AS
SELECT F.FlightID, (F.ArrivalTime-F.DepartTime) As FlightDuration
FROM FLIGHT as F
INNER JOIN RESERVATION as R
ON A.FlightID = R.FlightID
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER as C
ON C.CustomerID = R.CustomerID
WHERE F.DepartTime < Convert(Time, GetDate())
AND C.FirstName = ‘John’ 
AND C.LastName = ‘Smith’;
```

If I run this is says SQL command not properly ended! What am I doing wrong please help?

Comment: The CONVERT function in Oracle is for character set conversion. And is 'TIME' a column in any of the tables, and what is GetDate()? I think you're SQL is not written for Oracle but another DB engine.

Comment: Also the quotation character is `'`, not `‘`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you'd rather

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW viewa
AS
   SELECT f.flightid, (f.arrivaltime - f.departtime) AS flightduration
     FROM flight f
          INNER JOIN reservation r ON a.flightid = r.flightid
          INNER JOIN customer c ON c.customerid = r.customerid
    WHERE     f.departtime < SYSDATE
          AND c.firstname = 'John'
          AND c.lastname = 'Smith';
```

because

- table alias - in Oracle - doesn't support the `as` keyword
- you should get rid of *fancy* single quotes and use *straight* ones
- use supported function(s) - there's no `getdate` in Oracle, and `convert` is used for different purpose. I believe it is the `sysdate` you need

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your SQL server version for the right syntax to use near

```
'GetDate()) AND C.FirstName = ‘ John ’ AND C.LastName = ‘ Smith ’'
```

May I know your SQL database version.

Comment: Sandra doesn't use MySQL but Oracle (at least, that's what tag and question title say).

Comment: Thanks. It still tells me flightID is invalid identifier. Is it because I haven't got any data in my table yet?